# Using Tcp, why do large blocks of data get transmitted with a lower bandwidth then small blocks of data?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, windows-xp, network-programming

Using 2 PC's with Windows XP, 64kB Tcp Window size, connected with a crossover cable
Using Qt 4.5.3, QTcpServer and QTcpSocket

Sending 2000 messages of 40kB takes 2 seconds (40MB/s)
Sending 1 message of 80MB takes 80 seconds (1MB/s)

Anyone has an explanation for this? I would expect the larger message to go faster, since the lower layers can then fill the Tcp packets more efficiently.

Comment: the data size less than 64kb will pass through straight forward and data will lager than 64kb will be transfered in chunks of 64kb that process will take more time to split and Marge the data that's why it takes  more time.

Comment: @moon: Hogwash. Any time you'd save in splitting things up would be lost in network latency of opening so many connections.

Comment: @Pieter: Does the behavior still occur if you use the native socket facilities rather than the ones provided by Qt?

Comment: @Billy Good idea. I wouldn't be surprised if it was a QT bug - wouldn't be the first.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong either in Qt or in the OS. I wrapped a function around QTcpSocket::write that cuts up all my messages in chunks of 40kB. Now all my data gets sent at a rate of about 40MB/s. Cookies for the one who finds the cause of this :)

Comment: I reported this to Qt, apparently they changed the management of the buffers in between 4.5.3 and 4.7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bug in Qt 4.5.3

..................................

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to comment on without seeing your code.

How are you timing this on the sending side? When do you know you're done?

How does the client read the data, does it read into fixed sized buffers and throw the data away or does it somehow know (from the framing) that the "message" is 80MB and try and build up the "message" into a single data buffer to pass up to the application layer?

It's unlikely to be the underlying Windows sockets code that's making this work poorly.

Answer (score 1):

TCP, from the application side, is stream-based which means there are no packets, just a sequence of bytes.  The kernel *may* collect multiple writes to the connection before sending it out and the receiving side may make any amount of the received data available to each "read" call.

TCP, on the IP side, is packets.  Since standard Ethernet has an MTU (maximum transfer unit) of 1500 bytes and both TCP and IP have 20-byte headers, each packet transferred over Ethernet will pass 1460 bytes (or less) of the TCP stream to the other side.  40KB or 80MB writes from the application will make no difference here.

How long it appears to take data to transfer will depend on how and where you measure it.  Writing 40KB will likely return immediately since that amount of data will simply get dropped in TCP's "send window" inside the kernel.  An 80MB write will block waiting for it all to get transferred (well, all but the last 64KB which will fit, pending, in the window).

TCP transfer speed is also affected by the receiver.  It has a "receive window" that contains everything received from the peer but not fetched by the application.  The amount of space available in this window is passed to the sender with every return ACK so if it's not being emptied quickly enough by the receiving application, the sender will eventually pause.  WireShark may provide some insight here.

In the end, both methods should transfer in the same amount of time since an application can easily fill the outgoing window faster than TCP can transfer it no matter how that data is chunked.

I can't speak for the operation of QT, however.

Comment: Qt builds a framework on top of it, you can find a more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778049/what-is-qtcpsockets-behaviour-when-the-network-is-overloaded